# Modifying text contents based on operation on line number

Tags: bash, sed

Let's say I have this data in a text file:

```
line1 
line2 
line3
line4
line5
...
```

I want to change this text file based on a pattern using line number e.g. line number mod 3,line contents:

```
1,line1
2,line2
3,line3
1,line4
2,line5
...
```

How can I achieve this (preferably using sed)?

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to do in `sed` because it lacks arithmetic.  However, there are a couple of ways you can do it with `awk`:

```
awk '{ printf "%d, %s\n", (linenum++ % 3) + 1, $0 }' lines.txt
```

or

```
awk '{ print (linenum++ % 3) + 1 ", " $0 }' lines.txt
```

In both cases, `linenum` is being used to count the lines, then the modulo operation is used to calculate the remainder of the line count divided by 3.  The `1` is added to get the numbering scheme you requested.

`printf` provides a little "eye candy" to the program.

See `man awk` for details and other options.